# How to Get PHP style timestamp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have made an offline app and now I want the data to be able to sync online, for which I would have to use a log of actions performed with timestamps.

I need to generate and use timestamps in both JavaScript and PHP and I need them to be in the same format.

How can I generate the timestamps in javascript in the same format as that in PHP?

**EDIT:** I want it in some format such as "29/03/2014 12:14:30pm"

Comment: time() in PHP, getTime() in JS

Comment: I would ask...  what format do you WANT the timestamps to be in?  Because either Javascript or PHP can produce any number of different formats for timestamps depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Charlie74 I want it in some format such as "29/03/2014 12:14:30pm"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
Date.now();
```

Note: This will not work in IE8 and earlier
You will need to shim it like that:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { 
      return new Date().getTime(); 
    };
}
```

After that you can call Date.now() even in IE<=IE8